# converting string to date in php

Tags: php, date

First i entered e6 = 24-09-2011 as input type = "text" in previous page then:

```
  $a6 = $_POST["e6"]   ; 
  $time = strtotime( $a6 );
  $myDate = date ("y-m-d", $time ); 
  echo $myDate ;
  $n = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($myDate)) . " +$a7 month");
  $q = date("Y-m-d", $n);
  echo $q ;

out put: 11-09-24 2013-09-24
```

I want to print 2011 in place of only 11. What should I do ?? pls help.

Comment: just capitalize `y` in `$myDate = date ("y-m-d", $time ); `

Comment: If a user has given you the correct answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $a6 = $_POST["e6"]   ; 
    $time = strtotime( $a6 );
    $myDate = date ("Y-m-d", $time ); 
    echo $myDate ;
    $n = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($myDate)) . " +$a7 month");
    $q = date("Y-m-d", $n);
    echo $q ;
```

You needed to change all the lower case y to capital Y. [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

`$myDate = date ("y-m-d", $time );`
should be with a capital 'Y' like so :
`$myDate = date ("Y-m-d", $time );`

Php docs has a very good explanation on the data-string formatting: [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)